# c programming finds the two digit number that was repeated most

Tags: c

I have this code that the input is random for example :

```
33 32 65 55 44 pe *&44^ %123^
```

now I need to find which two digit number was repeaed most (and the number needs to contain digits from 1 to 9, which mean `10,30..` are not valid numbers), now what seperate between two digit number to another is every input exept for another number,
in this case I want the output to be 44 then I will print:

```
The winner couple is: 4 blue, 4 red.
```

now I thought the best way to do something like this is using 2D array, that when a input is valid I will apdate the array in the sutble place, and after that I will find the maximum place in the array.
here is my code so far :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 9

int is_digit(char c);
void update_array(int num[N][N]);
int find_max(int b[N][N]);

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int num[N][N];
    int maximum=0,a=0,b=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
      for(j=0;j<N;++j)
      {
       num[i][j]=0;
      }
    }
    update_array(num);
    maximum=find_max(num);
    a=maximum/10;
    b=maximum%10;
    printf("The winner couple is: %d blue, 4%d red.",a,b);
  return 0;
}

int is_digit(char c)
{
    if(c<'0'&&c>'9')
      return 1;
    else 
     return 0;

}

void update_array(int num[N][N])
{
char c;
int digit = 0;
int digits = 0;
int redIndex = 0;
int blueIndex = 0;
while (scanf("%c", &c) != EOF)
{
    if (is_digit(c))
    {
        digits++;
        digit = c -'0';
        if (digits == 1)
            redIndex = digit;
        else if (digits == 2)
            blueIndex = digit;
    }
    else
    {
        if (digits == 2)
        {
           (num[redIndex][blueIndex]++);
        }
        digits = 0;
    }
}

int find_max(int b[N][N])
{
   int max = b[0][0];
   int x,y;

   for (x = 0; x < N; x++)
   {
       for (y = 0; y < N; y++)
       {
           if (max < b[x][y])
           {
               max = b[x][y];
           }
       }
   }
   }

   return max;

}
```

the code gives me incorect output , i chicked all of the functions and they are good ,exept for update_array function i think there is something icorrect, basicly this function chicks where there is two digit number and update the suatble place in array, so i can then use fin_max function and find the maximum..
plz anyhelp of why it gives me incorect values, i know i should use debugg but i never knew about this untill now and i don't have the time to learn this now and use it cause i need to submit this in a couple of hours !

Comment: While it is a good start using a macro for the array length, you should use more self-explanatory names for macros and variables. `N` clearly is not.

Comment: Too many obvious errors. Please read a C book to learn the basics how functions work and start with something simple.

Comment: can you recommend a book ? this i need to submit today ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't recommend books. Just see the recommendation page here. But try to get the whole picture first!

Comment: which recommendation page ?

Comment: `update_array()`  most likely misses a closing brace.

Comment: You might use a debugger to help yourself. Try it, it's fun! :-)

Comment: i updated the code ! any help plz ?

Comment: Rolled back. Once you got answers, you must not change the code in significant places! This is no life-editing forum. If you want to add something, append it with a clear intro that this is an addition or similar.

Comment: `if(c<'0'&&c>'9')` is never true.

Comment: @chux: There are too many other errors/flaws/bugs/whatsoever ...

Answer (score 0):

In your code you do `if (isdigit(c))`, but `isdigit` *is a different (standard library) function*! You have to `#include <ctype.h>` to use it.

Comment: `isdigit` is not part of `string.h`. And OP does not use the library function anyway (the call is likely a typo). But good point he really should use the standard function.

Comment: @Olaf, oops, fixed that

Comment: @Olaf OP is coding `if (c>'0'&&c<='9')`.  Do you think using the standard library function `isdigit()`, adding the needed casting and testing against `'0'` like `if (isdigit((unsigned char)c) && c != '0')` is preferred?

Comment: @chux: Thanks for the comment. OP has completely changed the code in question. I rolled back, maybe my comment no becomes clear. I deduced the usage from the name, not the code (which is wrong anyway).

Comment: Olaf Yes - I see that - hard to answer a moving target.

Answer (score 0):

- Using `continue;` outside loop is illegal.
- You didn't declare nor define `w`.
- A semicolon is missing after what seems calling of function `w`.

Try this because `is_digit` is not used:

```
void is_digit(char c)
{
    (void)c; /* avoid warning for unused variable */
}
```

Note that this is invaiid because the return type is `void`:

```
void is_digit(char c)
{
    return (c>'0'&&c<='9');

}
```

Don't forget to add `#include <ctype.h>` to use `isdigit()`.

Also, replace

```
if (isdigit(c))
```

with

```
if (isdigit((unsigned char)c) && c != '0')
```

to avoid *undefined behavior* for passing out-of-range value and reject digit `0`.

Comment: i can use only: #include <stdio.h>
                       #include <stdlib.h> , the problem now in the code they tell me Ico forbids nested functions , what that mean ?

Answer (score -1):

You've declared the function with the name `is_digit()` and later you are using it with the name `isdigit()`.

---

So, after changing the above mentioned error, your code would look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 9

int is_digit(char c);
void update_array(int num[N][N]);
int find_max(int b[N][N]);

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int num[N][N];
    int maximum=0,a=0,b=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
      for(j=0;j<N;++j)
      {
       num[i][j]=0;
      }
    }
    update_array(num);
    maximum=find_max(num);
    a=maximum/10;
    b=maximum%10;
    printf("The winner couple is: %d blue, 4%d red.",a,b);
  return 0;
}

int is_digit(char c)
{
    if(c<'0'&&c>'9')
      return 1;
    else if(c>'0'&&c<='9')
     return 0;

}

void update_array(int num[N][N])
{
char c;
int digit = 0;
int digits = 0;
int redIndex = 0;
int blueIndex = 0;
while (scanf("%c", &c) != EOF)
{                              // <= while started
    if (is_digit(c))
    {                          // <= if started
        digits++;
        digit = c -'0';
        if (digits == 1)
            redIndex = digit;
        else if (digits == 2)
            blueIndex = digit;
    }                          // <= If ended
    else
    {                          // <= else started
        if (digits == 2)
        {
           (num[redIndex][blueIndex]++);
        }
        digits = 0;
    }                         // <= else ended
}                             // <= while ended

//where is the function ending?

} //hence another curly braces needed.

int find_max(int b[N][N])
{
   int max = b[0][0];
   int x,y;

   for (x = 0; x < N; x++)
   {
       for (y = 0; y < N; y++)
       {
           if (max < b[x][y])
           {
               max = b[x][y];
           }
       }
   }

   return max;

}
```

Comment: i fixed that but then i got this mistake : Iso forbids nested functions . where  i used the function find_max .. why, what they mean ?

Comment: @james It is because `find_max` is inside `update_array`. Fix your code, including indent.

Comment: i didn't get it, find_max is not inside update_array !

Comment: @james, I've indented your code, now you can easily see. That is why programmers stress on indentation, because it is da*n important.

Comment: horis , i didn't understad , what indented mean ?? (i don't undersatd english that good :\ )

Comment: now the problem is : in function is_digit control reaches end of non void function :\  every time i fix something another thing apear :( is there is something with is_digit function ?

Comment: @james, You do not need `else if` in `is_digit()`, just `else` will do, as the check is exhauative.

Comment: ok now the code works for the first time, i am gonna see if it gives me the correct output :\ thanks..

Comment: ok the outut is so wrong :'( , i think the main problem is in the update_array function ...

Comment: @james, Now you can run and debug and correct the program step by step

Comment: i don't know what debug mean ! we didn't learn something like this , still beginner here , i wish i have time to learn this now ! but i don't ,i need to submit this in  couple of hours, so i think everything i have done was a waste of time lol ...

Comment: @james, Just think of debugging is looking into your code, and trying to find the error/mistake. There are many tolls also for that, but since you do not have a lot of time, just try different inputs and try to make sense and understand why the program is behaving that way.

Comment: @Haris can you plz help me, how can i make a counter to find if there is more than one maximum ?

Comment: i updated the code and ot works but now i want to chick if there is more than one max ...

Comment: `isdigit` is a standard C library function, declared in `<ctype.h>`. I fyou write your own function `is_digit` and then call `isdigit`, the program will still link for this reason.

Comment: `is_digit('0')` has no return value.  `if(c<'0'&&c>'9')` is never true.